# Append new value to javax.json.JsonObject

Tags: java, json

The code that we already have return us `JsonObject`. What I want to do is to add a new key and the value for it.
For example, we have an object like this:

```
{"id":"12","name":"test"}
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
{"id":"12","name":"test","status":"complete"}
```

I didn't find what I need in documentation except using put method. So I wrote this code:

```
JsonObject object = getJsonObject();
JsonString val = new JsonString() {

    public JsonValue.ValueType getValueType() {
        return JsonValue.ValueType.STRING;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return "complete";
    }

    public CharSequence getChars() {
        return (CharSequence) "complete";
    }
};
object.put("status", val);
```

But it doesn't work, crashing with :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

I can't understand what is wrong. Have I any other option to complete such a task?

Comment: `JsonObject` is immutable and there is no convenient built in `merge` operation.  See the answer from @danail-alexiev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if object.put works but you can use the following way to append the details to JSON value:
You can create a different JSON object with the key and value that you want to add to the JSON object and the user `object.merge(status, complete, String::concat);`
merge() checks for the key:'status' in your JSON object if it does'nt find it then it adds that key:value pair or else it replaces it
.You are not able to compile it because you may not be using jre 1.8.

I've Just verified the following method:
Just create a new JSONObject(`org.json.JSONObject` not `javax.json.JsonObject`)

```
JSONObject modifiedJsonObject= new JSONObject(object.toString());
modifiedJsonObject.put("status", "complete");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe I do something wrong, but it doesn't compile at all: The method merge(String, JsonValue, BiFunction<? super JsonValue,? super JsonValue,? extends JsonValue>) in the type Map<String,JsonValue> is not applicable for the arguments (String, JsonValue, String::concat)
 The type String does not define concat(JsonValue, JsonValue) that is applicable here

Comment: It is because you may not be using jre 1.8. I've updated my answer with another way, now you can add as many fields as possible. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am not allowed to use third-party libraries (org.json), so I can't do it that way

Comment: @shiv Create a wrapper for the JSONObject and use it, in that case you can change the underlying third party API anytime you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `JsonObject` instances are meant to be modified.

I think your best option is to create a new object, copy the existing properties and add the new property to it.

You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Yeah, it seems there is the only way in my circumstances.